# query animation toggle the whole content

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

On a mobile site i've an navigation-icon (class: mob_navi_icon) on which a click moves the whole content (id: content_wrapper) to the left or moves it back. I' trying to build this with jQuery animation and toggle.

My jQuery:

```
 $('.mob_navi_icon').click(function() {
    $( "#content_wrapper" ).toggle(
       function() {
          $( this ).animate({ marginLeft: "-395px" }, "slow" );
       },
       function () {
          $( this ).animate({ marginLeft: "0" }, "slow" );
      })
})
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Thanks for any tips/help whats wrong.

Thomas

Comment: what specifically doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `toggle` function doesn't work like this - it doesn't accept two functions as parameters. The `toggle` function is used to show and hide matched elements. See jQuery domuentation:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

But you can implement it on your own. One possibility is to use a toggle flag like I did here (click on the box several times):

http://jsfiddle.net/YuKj3/1/

```
var box_toggle = false;
$("#box").click(function(){
    if(box_toggle = !box_toggle) {
        $( this ).animate({ left: "50px" }, "slow" );
    } else {
        $( this ).animate({ left: "0px" }, "slow" );  
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** Oh, I see that [toggle(handler1,handler2)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) used to be an event binding function in jQuery, however it was deprecated in version 1.8 and removed in 1.9. If you're using a newer verison of jQuery, this is the reason why it doesn't work.